# When operating with the code I created, the value is output as 'X-1' from the second value

Tags: python

```
numbers=[0,1,2,3,4,5,0]
print(numbers)

bbb=int(input("Enter the number at the list"))
       
for i, n in enumerate(numbers): 
        if n ==  bbb :
             print(numbers.index(bbb))
             numbers[i] = None
             numbers = [n for n in numbers if n is not None]
```

As you can see by executing the code that I entered above,
For the index value of the input value, in the first case, it operates normally with 'X'. (X is the index value for the input value.)

However, if the input value is duplicated, X will have several.
At this time, a problem arises.
When operating with the code I created, the value is output as 'X-1' from the second value.

I think it will be difficult to understand, so there is an example below.

When the code is operating normally:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,0]
input: 0
index: 0, 6
```

In the case of the code I wrote:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,0]
input: 0
index: 0, 5
```

I would appreciate it if you could give me even a little advice. Can you tell me how to solve this problem? please help..

Comment: Why are you changing the list while you're iterating over it and why are you using `numbers.index(bbb)` instead of `i`?

Comment: Do you **just** want the indexes or do you also want to remove the items from numbers? So that in the case of "0" entered your output would be `0, 6` but also that numbers is now `[1,2,3,4,5]` or does numbers remain `[0,1,2,3,4,5,0]`

Comment: The core issue you have is that when you iterate a list "forwards" and remove items during an iteration, you end up with indexes that don't reflect the initial state of the list. You want to iterate backwards starting at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find all indices first. And then remove the values:

```
numbers=[0,1,2,3,4,5,0]

bbb=int(input("Enter the number at the list"))

indices = [i for i, n in enumerate(numbers) if n == bbb]
numbers = [n for n in numbers if n != bbb]

print(*indices, sep='\n') # prints all indices one per line
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in your loop is index, so most of the code is unnecessary

```
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,0]
to_check = int(input("Enter the number at the list "))
for ind, val in enumerate(numbers):
    if val == to_check:
        print(ind)
```

Answer (score 0):

what i get from your question is you want the input value to get check from your list at what index does they exists :

**So here is the solution:**

```
numbers=[0,1,2,3,4,5,0]
bbb=int(input("Enter the number at the list"))
for i, n in enumerate(numbers):
    if n==bbb:
        print(i)
else:
    print('number not there in the list')
```

**Output img with two case :**

1. with the number which exist in list eg(0)
2. with the number that does not exist in list eg(7)

:

[image]

**If this help you plz vote my ans up**